# how to use a js variable inside google chart options (colors)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am building a Google chart and have this in this options code:

```
options: {
            'colors': ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'],
         'chartArea':  {width: '60%', left: 45},
         'legend' :'none',
         'title':'some chart title'
     }
```

the above works fine, but I need to use a variable as colors. So what I want to do is this:

```
var newcolors = "'#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'";
```

some more code here

```
options: {
     'colors': [newcolors],
     'chartArea':  {width: '60%', left: 45},
     'legend' :'none',
     'title':'some chart title'
 }
```

but I am getting a " ' is not a valid color string " error on the chart. I hope this is just a syntax error and I am jut being stupid. Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define newcolors, it's one long string.
When you do `'colors': [newcolors]`, it becomes an array with one element, that's a long string with commas in it.
What the options seem to expect is an array with multiple elements, one color each.

So when you define newcolors

`var newcolors = ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'];`
and `colors: newcolors`;

instead of

`var newcolors = "'#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'"`;

Comment: thank you, thank you, THANK YOU. I've just tested it! Works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Colors should be an array

> [How to Customize Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts)

```
var newcolors = ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']

options: {
     'colors': newcolors,
     ...
}
```